# wine, console program, gtk error messages

Tags: console, gtk3, ld, wine, window-decoration

From the linux console I run a windows console tool using:
`wine console_tool.exe ...`.
The console tool does not involve any windows. It's output is just textual.
Some output is added repeatedly after a given delay time.

However, besides the output of the `console_tool.exe` I get repeatedly the following error message also interleaved with the other output:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
```

I already tried to `export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0` but then the only change is that the error message changes:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
```

I also attempted to apt install the `:i386` version of the `libgtk3-nocsd.so.0` but it doesn't seem to exists.

I don't know why a console application may trigger a gtk error message. This is beyond my knowledge.

My preferred goal would be to tell wine that the .exe does not use windows and it does not need to not use gtk for windows emulation at all. However, as this may not be possible, my second preferred goal would be to solve the gtk issue.

Can you help me achieve at least one of those goals?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what the error messages mean. However, the `wineconsole` command runs console executable using wine. Example:

```
wineconsole console_tool.exe
```

Comment: Although a good idea, it doesn't help. I get the same result just in an additional console window.